# Python. trying simple encrypt and write to file

Tags: python

```
elif ans=="3":
         import datetime
         title  = datetime.datetime.now()
         jFile = open('Ejourn.txt' , 'a')
         jFile.write(str(title))
         jFile.write('\n')
         print("todays entry:")
         journal_entry = input()
         encrypt = ''
         i = len(journal_entry) -1
         while i >= 0:
           encrypt = encrypt + journal_entry[i]
           i = i = 1


         jFile.write(encrypt)
         jFile.write('\n' '\n')
```

For some reason it will not allow me to write it to a file. I allows me to input but leaves me there?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the error message you're getting?

Comment: No error message. It leaves stuck in the progra

Comment: What do you think `i = i = 1` does? It's for sure not decrementing anything

Comment: `i = i = 1` should be `i = i - 1`

Comment: `i = i = 1`, so `i` is always positive.

Comment: Sorry- it leaves me stuck in the program. Adding input but unable to exit and allow it to write to file

Comment: You have an infinite loop because of that typo.

Comment: that part i got from site. The progra

Comment: You misread the site.

Comment: program is for a journal and wanted to try adding a simple encrytion with hopes of understanding it myself.

Comment: Solution to remove it?

Comment: Just fix the typo. The second `=` should be `-`. Isn't it obvious what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Afraid not. Just begining the journey of learning

Comment: `=` is assignment, `-` is subtraction. The whole point of that line is to subtract 1 from `i` each time through the loop, repeating until it gets below `0`.

Comment: `i = i = 1` just sets `i` to `1`, it doesn't subtract from it. So it never gets below `0`.

Comment: Ahhh! I thought it seemd odd that = then it again = !!! But i thought it was just something i hadnt learned yet. Thank you!!

Comment: Do what I said earlier, change `i = i = 1` to `i = i - 1`.

Comment: Success! Thank you very much